# HashMap login system with user data

Tags: java, authentication, hashmap, setter, getter

I creating Java project with customers that are Registering and than login in to the system.

I have my setters and getters which are in class Setting

```
String password, name, lastname;
//getters and setters here
```

Than in a class Interface I create the HashMap

```
HashMap<String, Setting> mapList = new HashMap<String, Setting>(); 
//String is the Key Login and the values is the class with getters and setters
```

When I call method to put values in to HashMap

```
mapList.put(Login, password, name, lastname);
//I'm getting error saying that this types of values can not be stored in HashMap
```

Can any one help me with this problem ?

Ok, so I got solution for this problem for any that has the similar scenario.

When I used method put to add data in to hashmap it didn't store password, name and lastname

```
mapList.put(login, new User(password, name, lastname));
//this is solution for my scenario
```

Comment: What arguments does the `HashMap#put(..)` method expect?

Comment: Expects key and single value, but I want to store more values.

Comment: Did you mean to create a `Setting` object with those values and store that?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I prompt user to enter login, password, name and last name and I want to store it in hashmap Object Setting

Comment: Then do that. Create a new `Setting` object with the password, name, and lastname. Add the object to the `HashMap`.

Comment: And that is my Question, How do I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class named Setting

```java
public class Setting {
    public String password;
    public String name;
    public String lastname;
}
```

then create a hashmap as you are doing

```
HashMap<String, Setting> mapList = new HashMap<String, Setting>();
```

Not that your hashmap is accepting key as **String** and object of setting class as **Value**

So you can put the value into your hashmap as

```java
Setting setting = new Setting();
setting.password = "Your Password";
setting.name= "Your Name";
setting.lastname= "Your Lastname";
    
mapList.put("login", setting);
```

Mark as up if it works for you.

Comment: Vote for the answer if it serves for your problem.

Comment: You can't do like this mapList.put(Login, password, name, lastname); because hashmap only accepts only two parameters Key and Value both can be simple as string or can be an object or an arraylist. key has to be unique but value can be duplicated.